# Slidesjs not working with thumbnails

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm trying to use custom pagination so when I click on a thumbnail, the large image changes.  The example provided by the creator is broken.

http://slidesjs.com/examples/product/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

He is using jQuery version 1.5.1. But the `on` method is usable since version 1.7. So basicly this example should work if you use jQuery 1.7 or later.

So he did not update his example jQuery version but did use functionality from a later jQuery version.

**How did I found out?**
If you see the error you can see it is an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'
```

Which means the `on` method is not a method on `Object`.